# Conga Conductor says Report ID Doesn't Exist

Tags: conga

I'm trying to set up a Conga Conductor (aka Batch) to generate a pdf file and attach it to a student record.  I have a report set up and I copied the report ID and pasted it in the Report ID field of the Conductor.  However, when I try to run the Conductor, it tells me that the Report ID does not exist.  How can I correct that issue?

Comment: Have you checked with Conga support?

Comment: Conga errors are awful, see [Report Id Errors](https://support.conga.com/content/composer/report-size-cannot-be-determined-either-because-the-report-is-excessively-large-the-report-is-unavailable-or-the-report-type-is-matrix.-please-verify-the-report-id.). Its likely just an access problem but the messages are pretty confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the user that conductor is running as has access to the report...especially if you put it in your personal reports folder rather than a shared folder.